# Getting values from a legacy text field on a word doc

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-contentcontrol

I have an existing word doc that uses legacy text fields. I want to capture some of these values in VBA to use in a Subroutine. I read online that you could label a field with a bookmark and then reference it within the vba code like this

```
    Dim legacyTxt As String
    legacyTxt = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("legacyTxt").Range.Text
```

The problem I'm running into is that if the field is populated it appears the reference can no longer be found and I get the error *"The requested member of the collection does not exist"*

When the field is empty and I run my Sub the field has a default value of " FORMTEXT   ", and if I add a default value it returns a value similar to " FORMTEXT   Default Value"

Pretty sure the bookmark can be used for updated fields but not pulling info from them. Is there a way that I can do that without changing the existing fields to either ActiveX or RichTextControls?

---

*Following posted as answer by OP.*

### I see what i was doing wrong.

I had restrict editing turned off so when I would enter a value into the field I was writing over the field rather than entering a value. After I restricted editing and put this into my code  strFormFieldResult = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text1").result I got the expected results.

Comment: How were these fields populated originally?

Comment: The bookmark is normally assigned as a name for the field when it is created. There are default names assigned like Text2. *The careful user assigns more meaningful names.* That name is the bookmark for the field. See https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/master_your_formfields.html and https://gregmaxey.com/word_tip_pages/extract_data_from_document_file.html. If the user selects a formfield, copies and pastes, you end up without a name because bookmarks must be unique.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in a short document with a couple of "legacy" text fields (both populated):

```
Sub Test()

    Dim f As Object, b As Bookmark
    
    'actual field values...
    For Each f In ActiveDocument.Fields
        Debug.Print f.Result.Text, f.Code.Bookmarks(1).Name '>> {value} / name
    Next f
    
    'what you see...
    For Each b In ActiveDocument.Bookmarks
        Debug.Print b.Range.Text, b.Name    '>> FORMTEXT {value} / name
    Next b

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally legacy formfields automatically have a bookmark given to them when they are created. Right-click on the formfield and choose **Properties** to view the **Bookmarks** field. The exception to this occurs when formfields and copied and pasted, then the pasted copies will not have an automatic bookmark. In this case, you should add a bookmark in the Properties dialog.

This syntax will also work for getting the formfield result:

```
    strFormFieldResult = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text1").result
```

Answer (score 1):

I see what i was doing wrong. I had restrict editing turned off so when I would enter a value into the field I was writing over the field rather than entering a value. After I restricted editing and put this into my code  `strFormFieldResult = ActiveDocument.FormFields("Text1").result` I got the expected results.